# What practically "kills" the human brain without debilitating the person?

Tags: brain, recreational-drugs, irreversible-damage, neuroscience

For example, people say that drugs kill the brain but someone who becomes stupid and forgetful from years of smoking marijuana isn't literally brain dead. What specific drugs and other activities or actions "turn down" the human brain without debilitating the person?

Comment: This question could be phrased a lot better. A person can simultaneously have a genius level IQ and debilitating language disorder. Any damage to brain function can be characterized as debilitating. It is a matter of degree of debilitation and recognition that the brain handles language, logic, and memory independently, therefore can be harmed separately.